# AngularJS 1.5 component example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm working on an Angularjs project using `.component()` with `template` property, but I don't know how to use `templateUrl`. 
Is there anyone familiar with that can provides me a working example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To use the angular component properly I recommend using controllerAs syntax.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .component('groupComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/group.html',
        controller: function GroupController(){
              this.innerProp = "inner";
        },
        controllerAs: 'GroupCtrl',
        bindings: {
            input: '<'
        }
    });
```

And on group.html you can consume at the following way:

```
<div>
{{GroupCtrl.input}}
{{GroupCtrl.inner}}
</div>
```

From the parent control You can pass any parameter as binding to the component, in this case from the parent HTML:

```
<group-component input="someModel">
</group-component>
```

Comment: Thanks, What if we want to use the ngModel of a parent controller inside our component?

Comment: @MounirBoussetta I added the use from the parent to the answer, you will need to pass it as binding to preserve the component isolation, is it working for you?

Comment: From the docs for everyone else who is wondering what the '<' symbol does: 
Inputs should be using < and @ bindings. The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope.

Comment: How does AngularJS knows that <group-component> refer to groupComponent ? What if the component is named groupAlphaBetaCharlie ?

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` is the path to your template file.

**For example**

```
app.component('myview', {
  bindings: {
    items: '='
  },
  templateUrl: 'mycollection/view.html',
  controller: function ListCtrl() {}
});
```

**view.html**

```
<h1> Welcome to this view </h1>
```

As shown in above example, you must have `view.html` file inside `mycollection` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so far I can do like this, my problem is how to use `bindings` in an example, and how to inject a model into that templateUrl view.html.